# how to add sum and show in the table in php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

This is My Code.The problem is...i have 2 coulnm in db.leave type and leavecount.currently my code is going to the leave type and check the leave type against emp id and show the sum..like if half day has 2 count agaist emp id then its shows 2..but i want first check the leavetype and then check the leave count and then show the result.

```
<?php
    $hostname="localhost";  
    $username="root";  
    $password="";  
    $db = "usman";  

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  

    foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM ams 
        where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} 
        GROUP BY leavetype 
        HAVING leavetype = 'HalfDay'") as $HalfDay) 
       {  
       echo "<table ><tr ><td style='border: 0px; '>" . $HalfDay['cnt'] . "</td></tr></table>";    
                    echo "<br>"; 
       }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `leavetype` before `empid` but `HAVING` can't place middle of the query.

```
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM ams 
    sum(leavetype) as leavecount
    where leavetype = 'HalfDay' and 
    where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} and
    where leavecount > 2
    GROUP BY leavetype 
    HAVING leavetype = 'HalfDay'") as $HalfDay)
```

this code should work.

Comment: ..my problem is that i want to count the halfday in leavetype and get count from the leave count and then show the sum

Comment: 1st i want that sqli check the leave type if half day have 2 count then going to the leave count and sum the half day calculations

Comment: can you give a structure of your data table?

Comment: I have updated the query can you execute the query and give me the results!

Comment: empid & leavetype & datefrom & dateto & leave count

Comment: in leave count i used java to calculate the days

Comment: i want if emp id 900 has three medical in leave type the result should not b 3 because i am saved the the leave count in days..1mdecal entry for 1 day and 2nd may be for two day...so sum should be come from leave count

Comment: agaist emp id and medical

Comment: type of the leavetype filed?

Comment: absent,annual,medical,casual,halfday,shortleave,lwop